# Trying to alternate a panel and button's colours in Java Swing

Tags: java, css, swing, colors

I'm trying to use Java Swing to switch the colours of a panel and a button back and forth, but as it stands, it iterates through the for loop however many times I specify in a text field above, without changing colours, then changes colours once at the end. It's supposed to alternate each time it goes through the for loop.

```
timerBtn.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Stupid thing, why won't you switch?");
    System.out.println("Testing Red/Blue");
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    timerBtn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    String getText = textField.getText();
    System.out.println(getText);
    int parse = Integer.parseInt(getText);

    for (int i = 0; i < parse; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (timerColorTest == 0) {
            panel.setOpaque(true);
            System.out.println("Testing Blue/Red");
            timerBtn.setBackground(Color.RED);
            timerColorTest++;
            panel.repaint();

        } else {
            panel.setOpaque(true);
            System.out.println("Testing Red/Blue");
            panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            timerBtn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            timerColorTest--;
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't call `sleep` on the EDT, you're blocking it and the GUI will be unresponsive. Use a Swing `Timer` instead.

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623827/jbutton-flash-between-two-backround-colors/34624060#34624060)

Comment: I would recommend having a read of [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)